# Using variable passed in from psql command line, in function

Tags: postgresql

I can't figure out how to access variables inside my plpgsql function.  I'm using postgres 9.5 under Cygwin.

**functions.sql**

```
-- this works fine
\echo Recreate = :oktodrop

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_table(TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = $1 ) THEN
        -- syntax error here:
        IF (:oktodrop == 1 ) THEN
            DROP TABLE $1;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

psql.exe -v oktodrop=1 -f functions.sql

```
Password:
Recreate = 1
psql:functions.sql:13: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 5:         IF (:oktodrop == 1 ) THEN
                    ^
```

Comment: A simple `select $$ :oktodrop $$` wouldn't interpolate the variable, either: the contents inside strings are out of the scope of psql's parser. Aside from that, PG 9.5 provides `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename;`, so you probably don't need that function anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I've oversimplified your task (feel free to tell me if that's the case), but why not create the function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_table(tablename TEXT, oktodrop integer)
RETURNS text AS
$$
DECLARE
  result text;
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = tablename ) THEN
      IF (oktodrop = 1 ) THEN
        execute 'DROP TABLE ' || tablename;
        result := 'Dropped';
      ELSE
        result := 'Not Okay';
      END IF;
    ELSE
      result := 'No such table';
    END IF;
  return result;
END;
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

Then the implementation would be:

```
select drop_table('foo', 1);
```

I should also caution that because you have not specified the `table_schema` field, it's conceivable that your target table exists in another schema, and the actual drop command will fail because it doesn't exist in the default schema.