# Reference psql parameter inside PL/pgSQL anonymous block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I'd like to pass a parameter to an anonymous `PL/pgSQL` block via `psql` command line, then check that parameter in a conditional.

The relevant part of the SQL is here:

```
do $$
begin
    if (':para' = 1) then
        -- statements;
    end if;
end $$
;
```

I call this script as such:

```
psql -d dbname -v para=1 < script.sql
```

I receive the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ":para"
LINE 1: SELECT (':para' = 1)
            ^
QUERY:  SELECT (':para' = 1)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at IF
```

I tried using the case/when paradigm, which did not work either.

I am guessing that a `psql` parameter is not compatible with PL/pgSQL? Ultimately, my goal is to run a single `delete` statement if I pass `1` as a `psql` parameter, and not run it if I pass `0`.

Comment: Essentially the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753914

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `psql` parser can't see what is inside strings. This might be what you want:

```
delete from t
where :para = 1
```

Do it outside of an anonymous block. If you really need `PL/pgSQL` use a parameterized function:

```
create or replace function f(_para integer)
returns void as $$
begin
    if _para = 1 then
        --statements
    end if;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

And your script file will have:

```
select f(:para);
```

If you do not want to permanently add a function to the db do it all inside the script:

```
drop function if exists f_iu7YttW(integer);

create or replace function f_iu7YttW(_para integer)
returns void as $$
begin
    if _para = 1 then
        --statements
    end if;
end; $$ language plpgsql;

select f_iu7YttW(:para);

drop function f_iu7YttW(integer);
```

Give the function an unique name so you do not run the risk of dropping something else.

Comment: complementary techinique here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9981540/48729