# How to pass environment variables to a sql file from bash shell (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, bash, psql

I need to be able to pass environment variables, from a bash shell executing a `.sql` file using `psql`.

The `psql` command I am running is:

```
su postgres -c "psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -v dbname=example -v dbuser=example -e" < ./create-db.sql
```

Where I have put `example` is usually set to `$DATABASE_NAME` and `DATABASE_USER` respectively which is set in the bash script before executing the `psql` command.

The `create-db.sql` file is:

```
\connect postgres
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS :dbname;
DO $$BEGIN
    CREATE USER :dbuser;
EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_object THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'user already exists';
END$$;
ALTER ROLE :"dbuser" SET search_path TO :"dbname",public;
CREATE DATABASE :"dbname"
    OWNER=:dbuser
    ENCODING=UTF8
    LC_COLLATE='en_US.UTF-8'
    LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8'
    TEMPLATE=template0;
\connect :"dbname"
CREATE SCHEMA zulip AUTHORIZATION :"dbuser";
```

The variable substitution in the line `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS :dbname;` works, but everything after fails at the `CREATE USER :dbuser;` line fails and I have tried it as each of the following ways:

`CREATE USER :dbuser;`
`CREATE USER :'dbuser';`
`CREATE USER :"dbuser";`

And it always errors with:

```
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS example;
NOTICE:  database "example" does not exist, skipping
DROP DATABASE
DO $$BEGIN
    CREATE USER :dbuser;
EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_object THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'user already exists';
END$$;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 2:     CREATE USER :dbuser;
                        ^
```

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong with the above. Output of `psql -V` is `psql (PostgreSQL) 12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)`

Comment: Read this section [Dynamic Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). `CREATE USER` is a utility command and the complete command needs to be built textually.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have looked at that document, but still can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Without PLSQL, it seems to work :

```sql
\connect postgres
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS :dbname;
CREATE USER :dbuser;
ALTER ROLE :"dbuser" SET search_path TO :"dbname",public;
CREATE DATABASE :"dbname"
    OWNER=:dbuser
    ENCODING=UTF8
    LC_COLLATE='en_US.UTF-8'
    LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8'
    TEMPLATE=template0;
\connect :"dbname"
CREATE SCHEMA zulip AUTHORIZATION :"dbuser";
```

Comment: Unfortunately both didn't work, they still error about syntax issue at :

Comment: Yes the short version is that `psql` variables  will not be expanded in `plpgsql` functions per this post [Variables](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRAOU4pvGLhzeD%2BHBQ5a-c0onzPHL-gebOhieiy%3DjETUUQ%40mail.gmail.com) which points at this SO [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172524/passing-user-id-to-postgresql-triggers/13172964#13172964) for possible work arounds.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Passing parameters to an anonymous plsql bloc seems [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912786/reference-psql-parameter-inside-pl-pgsql-anonymous-block). I'll review the answer with a function...

Comment: Passing in parameters and using set variables are two different things. An anonymous function of any language cannot take parameters. Set variables cannot be used in a function, anonymous or not.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because u r using `$$` in line 5 of your SQL script when you say `DO $$BEGIN`. Your command line cannot handle this, but you can do:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y gettext-base &&
psql -c "$(envsubst < /scripts/init-db.sql)"
```

This installs the `envsubst` package which not get irritated by `$$`. In my case I `$DB_USER` this annotation to declare variables in my SQL file instead of `:"dbuser"`